# Set multiple render targets with OMSetRenderTargets using ComPtr<T>

Tags: c++, rendering, deferred-rendering, directx10

I've recently decided to get rid of pretty much all of the raw pointers from my Direct3D code, and I ran into a problem with using `ComPtr<T>` template with **multiple render** targets.

Microsoft suggests using `ComPtr<T>` for D3D instead of `unique_ptr<T>` or `shared_ptr<T>`. However even their example shows how to use it with `OMSetRenderTargets`, but I couldn't really find anything how to use it when you have to bind an array of managed objects.

Here's some code of my current solution:

```
class Texture{
public:
    void Initialize(const Bitmap &bitmap){ /* ... */}

    ID3D11ShaderResourceView* GetShaderResourceView() const { return this->m_pResourceView; }
    ID3D11RenderTargetView* GetRenderTargetView() const { return this->m_pTargetView; }
    ID3D11Resource* GetTextureResource() const { return this->m_pTexture; }

    ID3D11Texture2D* GetTexture2D() const { return static_cast<ID3D11Texture2D*>(this->m_pTexture); }

private:
    ID3D11ShaderResourceView * m_pResourceView;
    ID3D11RenderTargetView * m_pTargetView;
    ID3D11Resource * m_pTexture;
}

class Renderer{
public:
    void Initialize(const Window & targetWindow){ /* ... */ }

    void SetDepthStencilView(ID3D11DepthStencilView* pDepthStencilView = nullptr){
        n = n < RENDER_TARGET_MAX ? n : RENDER_TARGET_MAX;
        if (!n && pRenderTargetView == nullptr) {
            m_renderTargetViews[0] = m_myRenderTargetView;
        } else {
            m_renderTargetViews[n] = pRenderTargetView;
        }
    }

    void SetRenderTargetView(ID3D11RenderTargetView* pRenderTargetView = nullptr, size_t n = 0){
        if (pDepthStencilview == nullptr) {
            m_depthStencilView = m_myDepthStencilView;
        }
        else {
            m_depthStencilView = pDepthStencilview;
        }
    }

    void ApplyRenderTargetView(size_t count = 1){
        m_renderTargetViewCount = count < RENDER_TARGET_MAX ? count : RENDER_TARGET_MAX;
        m_deviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(m_renderTargetViewCount, m_renderTargetViews, m_depthStencilView);
    }

private:
    ID3D11Device* m_device; // device context, swap chain, raster state, etc ...
    ID3D11RenderTargetView* m_renderTargetViews[D3D11_SIMULTANEOUS_RENDER_TARGET_COUNT], *m_myRenderTargetView; // This is the screen as a default
    size_t m_renderTargetViewCount;
    // depth stencil buffer, etc ...
}


void some_use_case(Renderer & render){
    Texture colorMap;
    Texture normalMap;
    Texture positionMap;

    render.SetRenderTargetView(colorMap.GetRenderTargetView(), 0);
    render.SetRenderTargetView(normalMap.GetRenderTargetView(), 1);
    render.SetRenderTargetView(positionMap.GetRenderTargetView(), 2);

    // ... Render geometry
    // ... Render posteffects
}
```

Keep tracking and releasing all of the resources are way too tedious, and It's reasonable to introduce some smart pointer solution here. How could I replace the pointer definition, and how could I bind it `m_renderTargetViews` to `OMSetRenderTargets`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For single item arrays, you can easily use `GetAddressOf()` on a `ComPtr`, but for multiple item arrays you just create it on the stack:

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11RenderTargetView> m_renderTargetViews[D3D11_SIMULTANEOUS_RENDER_TARGET_COUNT];
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D1DepthStencilView> m_depthStencilView;

….

 m_deviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, m_renderTargetViews[0].GetAddressOf(),
    m_depthStencilView.Get());

...

ID3D11RenderTargetView* rtv[2] = { m_renderTargetViews[0].Get(),
    m_renderTargetViews[1].Get() };
m_deviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(__countof(rtv), rtv,
     m_depthStencilView.Get());
```

See [ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr).